# How to enable Nullable Reference Types feature of C# 8.0 for the whole project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

According to the [C# 8 announcement video](https://youtu.be/VdC0aoa7ung?t=137) the "nullable reference types" feature can be enabled for the whole project.

But how to enable it for the project? I did not find any new appropriate option in the Project Properties window in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1.

Can it be enabled for 'legacy' `.csproj` projects if the C# language version is changed to 8.0?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To enable Nullable Reference Types for all code in a project, add the following to its `.csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Alternatively open the Project Properties UI, search for *nullable* and select the option you want:

[image]

---

To enable this in all projects in the solution, add the property to a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file instead. You can use such a file to specify other properties across multiple projects too.

---

If you're targeting a version of .NET earlier than `netcoreapp3.0`, you'll also need to set `LangVersion` to 8 or higher, as Nullable Reference Types were added in C# 8:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

For older Visual Studio versions:

- You must be using at least VS 16.0
- In 16.0 preview 1, set `NullableReferenceTypes` to `true`.
- From 16.0 preview 2 to 16.1, set `NullableContextOptions` to `enable`.
- From 16.2 preview 1 onwards, use `Nullable` as above.

Comment: Note that the boolean logic might be a bit non-intuitive: `enable` means "enable the new C# 8.0 setting where types are non-nullable by default".  `disable` means "do it the old way where every type is nullable."

Comment: I also had to update <Project ToolsVersion="16.0" ...> and <VisualStudioVersion ...>16.0</VisualStudioVersion> from the older "15,0" before the <Nullable> would work on older non-SDK projects, even though they were correctly upgraded to framework 4.8 via the properties GUI of VS 16.3 RTM. Only the C#8 language version was respected without any additional project file editing.

Comment: @TonyWall I'm curious why you needed that. I just created a new .NET Framework Console App in VS 16.3.7 (i.e. non-SDK style project), added `LangVersion` and `Nullable` properties to the `.csproj` and it works fine. The project has `ToolsVersion="15.0"` too.

Comment: @DrewNoakes the problems come if you enable best practice code analysis and gets deeper. Even with these manual properties set the hard way the collection of tools currently used doesn't respect these new "standard" properties. MS need to align this and encourage the open source parts to come into line before the next RTM. VS is "Visual" Studio and we shouildn't have to mess about like this. In practice currently it is still necessary to add "#nullable enable" to the top of each file so this answer is not entirely valid after further experience, just the C# version part. Shame.

Comment: @TonyWall if you have `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` set in a project, you do not need to add `#nullable enable` to source files in that project.

Comment: @DrewNoakes No, as I said Nullable doesn't always work, especially if you use best practices like the new Code Analysis NuGet packages and highest warning levels / treat warnings as errors (maybe you missed some warnings/messages and didn't notice the problem still exists).

Comment: @TonyWall I do use those packages (I help to develop them in fact) and `TreatWarningsAsErrors` on several projects. My comment still holds, if you set it in the project, it is not needed in source. If you're experiencing that, then there is some other problem, potentially a bug in an analyzer. Please open a feedback ticket in Visual Studio with a repro. If you link it here I will have a look.

Comment: I like the old way, this new feature drives me crazy. All reference types nullable

Comment: @Moses that's fine, you can disable the feature. But you are giving up on type safety and exposing yourself to more issues at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to use the setting to not allow nulls expcept for classes in a specific folder?
What I'm thinking about is properties that model database fields, which can be null, but you don't want null referecne errors on other non database classes.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy not that I know of. The best I can think of is to ensure you set the nullable directive in only those files you want it to apply to.

Answer (score 36):

Note that this setting is changed between VS 2019 preview 1 and preview 2. With preview 2 or 3, you need this in your `.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The `<NullableReferenceTypes>` mentioned in the earlier answer (which, when I originally wrote this answer on 4th Feb 2019, had been marked as the accepted answer) was correct at the time that answer was written, but it is no longer recognized.

Comment: more information about available values for this option (`enable`, `disable`, `safeonly` etc): https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-reference-types.md#setting-project-level-nullable-context

Comment: Has this changed again in a recent release? This doesn't seem to work for me in Preview 4.2

Comment: Since Visual studio 6.2 <NullableContextOptions> has been simplified to just  <Nullable> (see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 31):

In addition to @DrewNoakes accepted answer, note that the nullable property can be set for **all projects at once** by adding a file called `Directory.Build.props` in the folder that contains your `.sln` file.

Just define your `Directory.Build.props` file like this:

```xml
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You will need to restart Visual Studio for this to take effect.

More about [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 24):

Worth noting that, by now, this is also an exposed setting in a project's Properties page:

[image: "Build" tab shows "Nullable" setting]

At least in VS2019 16.6+.

Comment: But not for old-style csproj.

Comment: I don't see that option.

Comment: This UI was only available in VS 2019. It changed in VS 2022 to the one shown in my answer.

Answer (score 15):

**For Visual Studio 2019 *Preview 2 & 3*, see [Ian Griffiths's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633538/how-to-enable-nullable-reference-types-feature-of-c-sharp-8-0-for-the-whole-proj#54521478).**

Solution for Visual Studio 2019 ***Preview 1***:

To enable Nullable Reference Types feature for the .NET Core project, add `NullableReferenceTypes` property to the `.csproj` file like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <NullableReferenceTypes>true</NullableReferenceTypes>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

As @JulienCouvreur referenced in comments regarding to https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4058, the new property is not yet supported in 'old' project system, but will be supported before C# 8.0 released.

Comment: Have you tried changing the target framework to `net472` ? How/where did you find that setting by the way? That reference would be *very* useful. I found many things that don't quite work as shown the video

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that tag was proposed in comments on YouTube by Mads Torgersen - the author of the video I linked in original question

Comment: This property isn't yet supported in 'old' projects. Issue is tracked by https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4058

Comment: Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 10):

### Legacy csproj format

You asked about the legacy `.csproj` format. Open up the project file in a text editor and make the following changes:

1. Add/change `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` in the `Debug` and `Release` PropertyGroup sections:

   ```xml
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
       <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
   ```
2. Enable support for nullable reference types by adding `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` to the main `PropertyGroup`:

   ```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
       <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
   ```

Tested with a .NET WinForms app using C# 8 and nullable reference types syntax in Visual Studio 2019 v16.2.0 Preview 3.

---

### SDK-style project files

SDK style projects are much simpler, and can be edited within Visual Studio. For these all you need is (in the same `PropertyGroup` as `TargetFramework` or `TargetFrameworks`):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

---

### Notes

- .NET Core 3.x projects target C# 8 [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version), so you won't need to specify the `LangVersion` for those projects.
- The default for .NET Framework projects is C# 7.3, and you don't get C# 8.0 even with `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`. You must explicitly set the language version to 8.0. Please refer to my answer to the question [Does C# 8 support the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020770/397817) for more details.

Comment: Nope, still nothing.