# Have upgrade a VS 2010 solution to VS 2019 over the years but need to get c#5 to upgrade to c#9

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2019

I have a working solution that started as a visual studio forms web project and solution using 2010 version. I have progressed over the years to VS 2019 and I'm using the latest framework of 4.8.

However, my C# version is 5. I need to upgrade to C# 9 but it is not an option I can find in the project properties window. I would be grateful for some help.

I did try creating a blank solution in VS2019 and importing all the  files. I did gain a project window with options I have not seen due to the newer project or solution version. I had 700 or so, errors on build and gave up. Perhaps if I had persevered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change C# Language Version for all of the projects in my solution in one place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434436/how-to-change-c-sharp-language-version-for-all-of-the-projects-in-my-solution-in)

Comment: Does this helps? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/