# Enable Nullable Reference Types feature of C# 8.0 for all classes in a folder branch

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm wishing to disable the Nullable Reference Types feature for all files contained in a folder and it's sub folders.

I know that I can put `#nullable disable` at the top of each file, and have read through the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633538/how-to-enable-nullable-reference-types-feature-of-c-sharp-8-0-for-the-whole-proj) for entire projects / solutions, however can't see a way to do it for specific folders.

Is it possible?

Thank you.