# NetCore 6 - Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-10.0

I updated a project to NetCore 6 and I am getting the warning:

```
Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

For example on a unit test:

```
String source = null;
String expect = null;

String actual = source.ToSafeBase64Url();
```

I am getting this warning in multiple places of my code.

How should I solve this?

Comment: what's the definition of `ToSafeBase64Url` ? this would work if `ToSafeBase64Url` is an extension method that accepts a `this String?` and returns a `String`, otherwise you'd need `String? actual = source?.ToSafeBase64Url()` for valid code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633538/how-to-enable-nullable-reference-types-feature-of-c-sharp-8-0-for-the-whole-proj should eventually be updated with "migrating to Net6/VS 2022 turns on nullable types" (or something along this lines...) `String` is non-nullable type...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the new .NET6 templates, [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) are enabled by default. You can see this if you open the csproj file, the line:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

That warning is telling you that you are assigning a null to a non-nullable type.  To fix it, make the strings nullable:

```
string? source = null;
string? expect = null;
```

Comment: I did that but I also get a `null` warning on my extension method: `source.ToSafeBase64Url()`. I could change the method to: `String FromSafeBase64Url(this String? source)`? ... I am not sure the path to follow as this affects many methods on my code.

Comment: Well yes, you would need to apply the same null-prevention to the extension method too.

Comment: string accept null values since 1817 and still today. What I'm missing? Something like more explicit code maybe?

Comment: The answer does not resolve the problem.. just move the problem in another point of the code :( For example when I configure IS4 `policy.RequireClaim("scope", options.ApiScope);` I get the warning `ApiScope could be null here`. In my case, `ApiScope` is never null, so why Should I set it as nullable?

Comment: @Ciccio Just because something isn't null doesn't mean it can *never* be null. These paradigms prevent us from ever getting into sticky situations like that. For example, what if your code was reorganised by someone else and that gave a null value for `options.ApiScope`?