# "Expression is always true" warning for reference type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, resharper

I have the following piece of code with warning `Expression is always true`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public MyClass(
        IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _logHandler = logHandler;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
            
    foreach (string group in groups)        
    {
        IClientProxy connection = _hubContext.Clients.User(group);
        if (connection != null) // Expression is always true
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I know that Resharper is very smart, however I cannot understand why it says `Expression is always true` as `IClientProxy` is reference type.
`IClientProxy` resides in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` namespace.
Do you know why Resharper says `Expression is always true`?

This is how `User` is declared in `public interface IHubClients<T>`:

```
public interface IHubClients<T> 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a <typeparamref name="T" /> that can be used to invoke 
    /// methods on all connections associated with the specified user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId">The user ID.</param>
    /// <returns>A client caller.</returns>
    T User(string userId);
}
```

### UPDATE:

If I add `?` sign:

```
IClientProxy? connection = _hubContext.Clients.User(group);
```

Then I will get the following warning:

> The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in
> code within a '#nullable' annotations context.

### UPDATE 1

Even if I use `var`:

```
var IClientProxy? connection = _hubContext.Clients.User(group);
if (connection != null)
```

then warning is arised `Expression is always true`:

[image]

Comment: Presumably this is using NRT annotations to declare that `User(group)` always returns a non-null value? i.e. the difference between `IClientProxy? Foo()` and `IClientProxy Foo()` when `#nullable enable` or the equivalent in the csproj is used

Comment: @MarcGravell I am sorry but what is NRT?

Comment: "nullable reference types" - compiler assisted decoration of when a reference is expected to possibly vs never contain null values; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Because you declared it as `IClientProxy connection` and not `IClientProxy? connection`, you are telling the compiler that you think that `connection` is not null. Thus, the compiler complains when you go on to test if the thing you said can't be null, is actually null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've tried to add `?` sign and I've got the following warning `The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.`

Comment: @MarcGravell Do you mean that if `User` property declared as nullable like this `T? User(string userId);`, then warning would vanish? I've added a piece of code where `T User(string userId);` is declared in interface. Please, see please my question

Comment: @Learner well, you'd need to use `IClientProxy?` too in the variable declaration - or just `var` (and it will be implied from the target method)

Comment: @MarcGravell I've tried, but it continue to show this warning `Expression is always true`. I've attached an image to my question.

Comment: So it seems that [`IHubClients<T>.Client(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.client?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is declared to not return null, so perhaps that's what causes it. Look at [the implementation here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/Internal/HubClients%2560T.cs) - it never returns null, as per the interface definition, so you shouldn't be checking it for null.

Comment: You should enable `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in your .csproj PropertyGroup

Comment: @MatthewWatson could you please explain how you figured out that **it never returns null**? Could you please explain in plain English? Feel free to make an answer! Thanks!

Comment: @theemee could you please explain or give a link to read more about `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

Comment: @Learner You can see that it never returns null in two ways: (1) The interface is declared as `public T Client (string connectionId)` rather than `public T? Client (string connectionId)` (i.e. it doesn't have the `?` to indicate that it can be nullable. (2) Inspecting the implementation confirms that the code always returns non-null.

Comment: @Learner https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we should note that the warning is from Resharper, and not the actual compiler. If you disable Resharper, that particular warning will go away.

That said, it is a valid warning. To understand why, consider the following interface definition:

```
public interface IDemo<T>
{
    public T Func();
}
```

That definition states that `Func()` will *not* return null. If it *could* return null, it would be defined using `T?` thus: `public T? Func();`

A simple implementation of that interface could look like this:

```
public sealed class Demo<T>: IDemo<T> where T: new()
{
    public T Func()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

This compiles OK. However, if you change the implementation of `Func()` to:

```
public T Func()
{
    return null;
}
```

you will get a real (not Resharper) compile error:

```
error CS0403: Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.
warning CS8603: Possible null reference return.
```

Now consider this code (where I chose an arbitrary type with a default constructor for illustration, in this case `Random`):

```
IDemo<Random> test = new Demo<Random>();

if (test.Func() != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not null");
}
```

This provokes the Resharper warning that you're seeing, the reason being that `IDemo<Random>.Func()` has been specified to return non-null, as explained above.

The method you are using is declared as [`public T IHubClients<T>.Client(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.client?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - i.e. it returns `T` and not `T?` - which means it can never (or should never) be null.

Thus when you check it for null, Resharper is warning you because you should not need to do that.

Comment: thank you very much for thorough answer! Thanks a lot! It is very cool!